# Sphinx 3 not starting on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, thinking-sphinx

When I search it raises this exception:

Mysql2::Error: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0

-- My Gemfile.rb --

```
gem 'mysql2',          '0.3.12b5'
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '3.0.3' #'2.0.11'
gem 'flying-sphinx',   '1.0.0' #'0.8.4'
```

I'm running Rails 4 and Postgres

I've run the heroku sphinx conf

Comment: Much better to send an email to support@flying-sphinx.com with the details of the rake tasks you've run and the app's name, and then I can investigate directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. Although the docs say that the flying-sphinx gem does all the configuration for you after the inital configuration. You still have to run these two commands:

```
$ heroku run bundle exec flying-sphinx index
$ heroku run bundle exec flying-sphinx start
```